# Web Design and Usability

Tags: user-interface, web

We have a webpage that contains three grids full of data. The grids are large so the users scroll down the page to view the data in each grid. We thought that rather then making the user scroll since page can get large. We'd create a tabbed view of the page with three tabs each one containing one of the girds. So rather then three grids on one page and the user needs to scroll, they just click on the tab and it contain the grid they want. One user told us this design was terrible and that its easier to scroll all the way down the page then making a click.

Personally I disagree with that.

I did a google search to see if I could find any data as to which design is better, but didn't find much. My question is which design is better? Would you rather make user scroll the page and keep all three grids on one page, or put each in its own tab? I couldn't find an excepted standard for this design.

Comment: You may be better off asking this on the [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: The user is generally always right and the designer is generally always wrong unless he/she consults the user. So I'd recommend actually doing research and polling your user base. A single user is insufficient data and asking the opinion of non users is not data at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the tab approach.  Here is some [guidance from Yahoo on when to use tabs](http://developer.yahoo.com/ypatterns/navigation/tabs/moduletabs.html) and I believe your situation meets this criteria, but you will have to be the judge because you know more about the context on how this is used. If you have the capability to do so, the best way to determine the best user interface is a usability study with your customers.  Poll them on the change and get feedback.

Answer (score 1):

If the tab links are at the top of the page a user has to scroll back up to switch between contents. This is not much of a problem when the content in each tab is short. In your case, when it is very large this could get annoying.

Maybe you could place an easy to reach "Back to top" link inbetween the data or at the bottom of the tab. Or you could try breaking your contents even further apart, if that's an option.